# com.ibm.jsse2.util no trusted certificate found

Tags: java, jvm, lotus-domino, agents

I created a java agent that needs to connect to an API internaly. The protocol used is HTTPS. When the agent tries to connect to the API it throws the following error:

com.ibm.jsse2.util: no trusted certificate found. This all is running on a Domino 9.0.1fp3 server. The SSL certificate is a self signed certificate with a custom certificate authority.

I tried the following solution http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21588966 but to no success. Even when we restarted the server it does not correctly pick up the certificate chain. As a last resort we created a little java class that ignores SSL certificates that are self signed. But ofcourse this is not a great solution.

I was wondering if someone also encountered this issue and knows how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently IBM forgot to mention that you actually need to restart the whole server for this to work....